# Execute Gulp tasks and watches remotely

Tags: node.js, git, gulp, remote-desktop

I have installed Git and Node.JS in a Windows Server with Windows Remote Desktop in order to use Gulp.

If I'm connected with remote desktop, I don't have any problem in executing gulp, but my problem is that I want to execute these tasks and watches in a local computer without using Remote Desktop Connection.

I don't know whether there exists a script that can execute Node.js command prompt in my server (under my local computer) or any other solution...

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell. You can remote into your server with powershell, then run node and gulp commands.